# Embed secure iframe content on secure site from separate domain. Will this work?

Tags: security, iframe, https

I need to display a secure form from site A on an insecure site (site B).

I've found quite a bit of information on the dangers of embedding content from a secure site on a non-secure site using iFrame. I'm sold that this is a no-go.

My question is this: will making site B https solve my problem? Can I embed a secure form on a secure site (two different domains) using iFrame?

Some things that might help: the form is generated on a site called Blackbaud Sphere which gives me very little control over how the page is generated. It's like a google form but with financial data, purchases, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It is perfectly valid to have an iFrame from a different domain provided that you are not mixing secure and insecure content.